# TRIM related kernel panic every restart

Tags: trim, kernel-panic, osx-el-capitan

I installed the El Capitan GM beta and now every time I restart I'm greeted by this:

[image: kernel panic]

I used [this guide](http://shaah.in/post/97565554337/boot-failure-on-mac-os-1010-after-enabling-trim) to fix the issue, but I need to run it every restart to get around the kernel panic.

Anyone having this issue as well?

Comment: iirc, needs VBox 5 - it's nothing to do with TRIM, which has been fine since 10.10.4

Comment: @Tetsujin VirtualBox? Why would it be affected by virtualisation?

Comment: @Tetsujin oh you're right, I didn't even bother reading the backtrace. Will try!